# Swift Protocol: property that is subclass of: someClass, instead of being of that class

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm trying to create a protocol that describes a property that is a subclass of a certain class instead of being of that class.

I would like to know if something like this is possible.

```
protocol {
   var prop : T where T: SomeClass { get set} // something like this
}
```

versus

```
protocol {
  var prop : SomeClass {get set}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `associatedtype` in your protocol definition

```
protocol pp {
    associatedtype T where T: SomeClass
    var prop : T  { get set} 
}
```

Comment: You can still say `T = SomeClass` though.

Comment: @Sweeper Doesn't `= ` mean that T must be of type `SomeClass` while `: ` means of type `SomeClass` or inherit from `SomeClass`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I mean in a class that conforms to `pp`, you can still say `typealias T = SomeClass` and have `prop` to be of type `SomeClass`. I don't know whether the OP wants that or not.

Comment: What i'm tryng to accomplish:

I have a class that is a UIView. It can contain either an SVG image or an ImageView.
 
I subclass this class to make custom components. I create an interface to interact with that class as to avoid writing redundant api's. The issue is that I want to be able to extend those controls to any class that subclasses that SVG/ImageView class.